# Codenvy - Bitnami Express Stack : what is mongodb user/pwd?

Tags: mongodb, express, bitnami, codenvy

I installed the Bitnami Express Stack on Codenvy (https://codenvy.io).

-> Now I need to configure the connection to the database in my project.

Simple question : How to connect to mongo (what is the user/pwd)?

```
//------------------------------dbSettings
config.mongoConnectionString = '';
// The connection string for your MongoDB Installation.
// Example: config.mongoConnectionString = 'username:password@example.com/mydb';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at this file `config/mongodb.js`. There you can find also some tips in order to connect to the database.